# How to retrieve image from database

Tags: android

This is my code which inserts an image in a database. How do I retrive that same image from the database when click on browsebutton2?

```
BrowseButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.BrowseButton);
BrowseButton2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.BrowseButton2);

adapter = new ContactImageAdapter(this, R.layout.screen_list, imageArry);
BrowseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.facebook);

        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();

        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
        db.addContact(new Contact("FaceBook", imageInByte));
    }
});

BrowseButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to fetch image from DB after getting cursor.

```
 Bitmap fetchedBitmap = null;     
    public static byte[] b = null;
if(cr.getBLob!=null){
        b = cr.getBlob(ColumnIndex); // Column index from which the image have to be fetched
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
        fetchedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bais);

}
```